# Euclid algorithm greatest common factor

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A be the greatest common factor of 9883529 and 759345

Find A using Euclid’s algorithm, and hence find integers x and y so that A = 9883529 x + 759345 y.

how do you use Euclid's algorithm ?

Comment: There's an [example of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Description) which might be helpful.

Comment: thank i have read it but i still don't get it much due to my english isn't that good

Comment: what do you mean by $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$9883529=759345(13)+12044$

$759345=12044(63)+573$

$12044=573(21)+11$

$573=11(52)+1$

$11=1(11)$

Hence the greatest common divisor will be $A=1$. Now Look at the reverse procedure:

$1=573-11(52)$

$11=12044-573(21)$

$573=759345-12044(63)$

$12044=9883529-759345(13)$

So by substitution we have:

$1=573-(12044-573(11))(52)=$

$-626288+573(573)=$

$=-626288+573(759345-12044(63))=$

$=-36099(12044)+434478397=$

$=-36099(9883529-759345(13))=9883529(-36099)+759345(469287)$

Hence $x=-36099$ and $y=469287$